# Why am I getting Segmentation Fault error instead of StackOverflow error in mono?

Tags: c#, android, mono

I have compiled mono for Android (ARM) and it's working very well.

Code: err.cs:

```
using System;
namespace E
{
    class E {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERR");
            e();
        }

        private static void e(){e();}
    }

}
```

On PC am i getting this output:

```
ERR
Stack overflow: IP: 0x407cb1b7, fault addr: 0x7ffc4dabbff8
Stacktrace:
  at E.E.e () <0x0000b>
  <...>
  at E.E.Main (string[]) <0x0001f>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

But on Android i'm getting segmentation fault (output):

```
ERR
Segmentation Fault
```

Can I do anything with this to catch an exception and write to logcat instead of closing my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net and Mono handle segfaults differently when they occur in native/non-managed code.

Under Mono, if the segfault is tripped by native code then you will get a stack trace and the program is aborted, if the seqfault is tripped by managed code it is handled as a managed exception.

FYI: There was a recent discussion about *nix segfault handling on the mono-dev list: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/SIGNAL-Segfault-in-native-function-called-by-managed-code-tt4666581.html